# Cómo puedo resolver este problema al instalar Node JS?

Tags: nodejs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al intentar instalar Node js tengo este problema, he intentado varias soluciones que he visto en youtube, pero aun no lo he podido solucionar.

Espero poder solucionarlo y empezar a practicar con node JS

Comment: Buen día, hay un post con la solución de ese error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61325928/i-cannot-reinstall-node-js-on-windows-10

Comment: Una forma de usar Node sin instalarlo, sería [descargar](https://nodejs.org/es/download/current) la versión **zip**. Descomprímela y renombra el directorio, que quede, por ejemplo en `C:\Node`. Finalmente agregas esa ruta a la [variable de entorno](https://www.google.com/search?q=agregar+variable+de+entorno+path) PATH de sistema.